# How to take a specific word from a dynamic string

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to take or select a specific word from a dynamic string value using c#.

Example :

> Here is some Text before **Vol.20** Here is some text after

**I want to take => Vol.20**

> Here is some Text before **Vol.1** Here is some text after

**I want to take => Vol.1**

> Here is some Text before **Vol.777** Here is some text after

**I want to take => Vol.777**

As you see in the example always there is text before and after Vol.20 & Vol.1 & Vol.777 also the only constant in this string is Vol.[number]

I only want to take the Vol.Number as string and save it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RegEx` for that, for example:

```
string str = "Here is some Text before Vol.1 Here is some text after";

Regex rg = new Regex(@"Vol.\d*"); //If number reqired use Vol.\d+
Match match = rg.Match(str);
string result = match.Value;
```

`match.Value` will return empty string if no match will be found, or you can use `match.Success` to check if there is a match.

Of course you can do it without regex, for example this way:

```
string result = string.Concat(str.Split(' ').Where(s => s.Contains("Vol.")));
```

but I will prefer regex version.

All this versions for if there is only one `Vol.[Number]` inside string, for multiple instances, you can do this:

```
string str = "Vol.551 Here is some Text before Vol.1 Vol.12 Here is some text after Vol.143";

Regex rg = new Regex(@"Vol.\d*"); //If number reqired use Vol.\d+

Match match = rg.Match(str);

MatchCollection matches = rg.Matches(str);

foreach (var item in matches)
{
    //Do something with item.Value
}
```

And non-regex version:

```
string[] matches = str.Split(' ').Where(s => s.Contains("Vol.")).ToArray();
```

Again, I will prefer regex version over above one. But if your strings is not too big and you have no issues with performance, you can use either of them.

References: **[Regex Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2)**

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer but actually the result is empty string .. i should say that whole example or sentence is string 100% . so i think there something wrong .. also i tried both solutions , by RegX and query both same results

Comment: @DummiesEBooks Can you post your actual string containing `Vol.[Number]`?

Comment: Since it's case sensitive it was my fault , i just saved it as vol not Vol ..you answer is true and complete . thanks alot

Comment: @DummiesEBooks One more thing, you can use `Regex rg = new Regex(@"Vol.\d*",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);` to ignore case if it is necessary.

Comment: Well That's So great then and you did the Help til end, Thanks and i appreciate your help

Comment: Just one more last thing please and sorry to make this so long as well if you add it to the answer .. if same example but Vol 20 so there is space and not dot @SeM

Comment: @DummiesEBooks for that you can do `Regex rg = new Regex(@"Vol\s\d+");`

Comment: You are the best just in case for future if change it to float number like Vol.1.1 or Vol.5.5 is it gonna be Regex(@"Vol\s\d+"); or something else and i really trying to learn as much as i can to make my self better. So please don't upset from my unstopped questions

Comment: @DummiesEBooks No problem, you can use `@"Vol.\d+(.\d+)?"`, it will return all cases with space, and int and float numbers. There are tons of material about regex online, if you want some pattern, just search it on google and you most probably will get an answer. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot .. You really helped me :)